# How to set the top level variable when creating a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

I have a foreach loop inserting data into a multidimensional array.

```
    foreach ($charts_list as $chart_list) {
      $category = $chart_list->category;
      if (isset($chart_options[$category])) {
         $chart_options[$category][] = $chart_list;
      } else {
         $chart_options[$category] = array($chart_list);
      }
    }
```

I am getting an array like this:

```
array:2 [▼
  "twitter" => array:3 [▼
    0 => {#271 ▼
      +"id": 1
      +"option_id": "DJ8RhoB"
      +"title": "Followers Growth"
      +"description": "See your followers growth"
      +"category": "twitter"
      +"created_at": "2016-05-09 10:44:54"
      +"updated_at": "2016-05-09 10:44:54"
    }
    1 => {#272 ▼
      +"id": 2
      +"option_id": "tqP3Bri"
      +"title": "Friends growth"
      +"description": "See your friends growth"
      +"category": "twitter"
      +"created_at": "2016-05-09 10:45:24"
      +"updated_at": "2016-05-09 10:45:24"
    }
    2 => {#273 ▼
      +"id": 3
      +"option_id": "v74DudJ"
      +"title": "Statuses count"
      +"description": "See your content growth"
      +"category": "twitter"
      +"created_at": "2016-05-09 10:45:46"
      +"updated_at": "2016-05-09 10:45:46"
    }
  ]
  "facebook" => array:1 [▼
    0 => {#274 ▼
      +"id": 4
      +"option_id": "fXj8wU5"
      +"title": "Friends growth"
      +"description": "See your friends growth"
      +"category": "facebook"
      +"created_at": "2016-05-09 13:08:21"
      +"updated_at": "2016-05-09 13:08:21"
    }
  ]
]
```

On the top level array I need to set it as `'category' => $category` which should print `"category": twitter`. I've tried setting the `$chart_options[$category]` as `$chart_options['category' => $category. But I get a parse error`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ']'`. How would I set the the top level array as a category?

Comment: At which line you got this error ? and can you pls update expected array format?

Comment: I changed the `else` statement to `$chart_options['category' => $category] = array($chart_list);` to try and set the variable. Thats where I get the error.

Comment: It should be `$chart_options['category'][$category] = array($chart_list);`

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @MattPrelude Basically instead of the array being printed as `"twitter" => array:3` I need it to be printed as `"category": "twitter" => array:3` so that  I can refer to this element in the view.

Comment: @kevinabraham There is no colon syntax in PHP arrays, do you want twitter/facebook to be values of category like:

array(
  'category' => array(
    'facebook' => ...,
    'twitter' => ...
  )
) or something else?

Comment: @MattPrelude Kind of I would need it to be array( 'category' => "twitter", 'category' => "facebook" ) )

Comment: @kevinabraham You can't have duplicate keys in an array. What are you looking to accomplish?

Comment: @MattPrelude Im using MVC structure and in the view I need to refer to the top level of the array so trying to refer to "twitter" or "facebook" as part of a foreach loop. But because its just "twitter" or "facebook" Im getting an error when trying to set that as text in the view.

Comment: @kevinabraham What's wrong with `foreach($chart_options as $category => $options)` ?

Comment: @MattPrelude I get a `Trying to get property of non-object` error.

Comment: @MattPrelude Sorry. You were absolutely right. Your `foreach($chart_options as $category => $options)` was the answer. If you create an answer I will select it.

Comment: @kevinabraham Thanks, I created an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're actually just trying to access the keys in your array, alongside the values.

PHP foreach allows you to access keys of an array by specifying an additional parameter, instead of the typical:

```
foreach ($array as $value)
```

You can do:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @MattPrelude. Helped me out a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear but I guess you want this:

```
$chart_options['category'] = $category;
```

Comment: Sorry if its not clear. Basically instead of the array printing `"twitter" => array:3` I need it to print `"category": "twitter" => array:3` for each of the records in the top level.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to try

`$chart_options['category'][$category][] = $category;`

Comment: Tried that it creates a further nested array inside category. My issue is that instead of `array:2 [▼
  "twitter" => array:3 [▼` being a element in the array on its own. I need to refer it to something so I can call it in the view. something like `"category": "twitter" => array:3`

Comment: $chart_options[$category][] = $category; Then jasonencode($chart_options)

Answer (score 0):

Add element `category` in else part.

**Your Code**

```
$chart_options[$category] = array($chart_list);
```

After replacing it will looks like below

```
$chart_options['category'][$category] = array($chart_list);
                  ^
```

**Full code**

```
foreach ($charts_list as $chart_list) {
  $category = $chart_list->category;
  if (isset($chart_options[$category])) {
     $chart_options[$category][] = $chart_list;
  } else {
     $chart_options['category'][$category] = array($chart_list);
  }
}
```